# Question involving eigenspaces and generalized eigenspaces

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

[Question image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwQjZ.png)

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $T$ with corresponding eigenspace and generalized eigenspace $E_{\lambda}$ and $K_{\lambda}$, respectively. Let $U$ be an invertible operator on $V$ that commutes with $T$ (i.e. $TU = UT$). Prove that $U(E_{\lambda}) = E_{\lambda}$ and $U(K_\lambda) = K_{\lambda}$.

I need to solve the question given above; however, I am unsure of how to proceed exactly; am I required to use the invertibility of $U$ to somehow show the two equalities? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You would certainly need invertibility of $U$ when showing $E_{\lambda} \subseteq U(E_{\lambda})$ and the corresponding inclusion for $K_{\lambda}.$

Comment: Please don't use generic terms like "question" in the title. All posts on this site are questions – imagine how the main page would look and how inefficient it would be if everyone did that.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that $x \in E_\lambda$ if and only if $(T - \lambda I) x = 0$ (where $I$ denotes the identity operator). Show that if $x \in E_\lambda$, we also have $(T - \lambda I) Ux = 0$.

In the same vein, note that $x \in K_\lambda$ if and only if there is a positive integer $k$ for which $(T - \lambda I)^k x = 0$